# Is there a way to upper case a JSON value before binding it - using SpringBoot?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I am working on a SpringBoot REST service.  The REST service works when the UI sends the right JSON values (formatted).

Sometimes the UI team will forget to upper case a property value and cause an exception.  I want to make the REST service handle such cases.

JSON property is being POSTed as

```
"category":"patient"
```

It is supposed to be POSTed with uppercase.

```
"category":"PATIENT"
```

The Java object property category is a ENUM

```
public enum StaffCategory {
    PATIENT, EQUIPMENT
}
```

The ui model object

```
@JsonProperty("category")
private StaffCategory category;

@JsonProperty("category")
public StaffCategory getCategory() {
    return category;
}

@JsonProperty("category")
public void setCategory(StaffCategory category) {
    this.category = category;
}

@JsonProperty("category")
private StaffCategory category;
```

This is the error I get

```
    Can not deserialize value of type model.constants.StaffCategory 
from String "patient": value not one of declared Enum instance names: [PATIENT, EQUIPMENT]
```

Comment: *Sometimes the UI team will forget to upper case a property value and cause an exception* - This is the perfect scenario for a `400 Bad Request`. You shouldn't tweak that server-side. The "UI team" should pass consistent data.

Comment: I agree. The UI team should do things properly. Or use numbers instead.

Comment: What Jackson version you are using?

Comment: BackEnd is a seperate Service. You should not tweak any well-written code just to handle the UI team's incapabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Although UI team should stick to backend API specs, still you can use ObjectMapper configuration to overcome this specific scenario:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS, true);
    return mapper;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to convert it to uppercase because it lowers readability and also  avoids maintainability.You only need to change your `Enum` definition as:

```
public enum StaffCategory {
    PATIENT("patient"), EQUIPMENT("equipment");

    private String value;
    private StaffCategory(String value) { this.value = value; }

    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() { return this.value; }
}
```

> This way it get easily deserialized with no breaking your code or facing any problems.